# Mongoose .pre not saving hashed passwords to the DB

Tags: mongoose

working with Passport and mongoose, and I'm trying to hash the passwords saved to the database, and it's simply not happening.

I have the model defined, and I can confirm that the object is being written to the database, so it must be in the block where my pre-save middleware is defined.

```
UserSchema.pre('save', (next) => {
    console.log('Pre-Save Hash has fired.')
    let user = this;
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });
});
```

Not sure why it's saving the password field in clear text when I clearly have something in place. It's probably implemented incorrectly.
(**the console.log in the middleware does log to the console.**)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a regular function instead of an arrow function for your pre-save callback to ensure that `this` references the document being processed:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  console.log('Pre-Save Hash has fired.')
  let user = this
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) console.error(err)
    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
      user.password = hash
      next()
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: i have this same issue and i am using regular function.. console even logs the correct this object right before calling next() and the database is still in clear text...